Kernel crash in PolynomialMod
The following code runs correctly
PolynomialMod[1-2x+x^(3/2)+I x^2, x^(3/2)]
PolynomialMod[1-2x+I x^2, x]

The following code causes an overflow error:
PolynomialMod[1-3/2x +I x^2, x]
(* General::ovfl. Overflow occurred in computation. *)

And the following code causes the kernel to crash!
PolynomialMod[1-3/2x+x^(3/2)+I x^2, x^(3/2)]

Is this a bug? How can I run it correctly?

I can confirm the crash in 14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024). A crash is almost always a bug, and you should report it to the technical support. (Let us know when you do it, or someone else will do it.)

I don't find it a bug: PolynomialMod deals with rationals and rational functions over rationals, but x^(3/2) is not a polynomial. You incorrectly use a command.

Another example of such a sort  is  PolynomialMod[1 - 3/2 x + y + I x^2, x^(3/2),   CoefficientDomain -> Rationals] which returns 1 - (3 x)/2 + y.  Unfortunately, the command is not equipped with foolproof.

@user64494, the expected behaviour of a function being called with wrong argument(s) is to throw an error message, not crash the kernel.

If you managed to crash the kernel, that is obviously a bug that should be reported. Please report bugs to Wolfram directly, not here on this site.
